# Heroku | Error: Could not find or load main class Main

Tags: java, heroku

I'm following https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#run-the-app-locally
When I run command **heroku local web** it's error

> [WARN] No ENV file found 
>   [OKAY] Trimming display Output to 138 Columns
>   1:51:20 PM web.1 |  Error: Could not find or load main class Main
>   [DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null 1:51:20 PM web.1 Exited
>   Abnormally

**My Procfile**

```
web:    java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main
```

Thanks all

Comment: You must make sure that you have the .env file from https://github.com/heroku/java-getting-started in your folder. Is this file there?

Comment: thanks, I added new file .env, it's resolve the first line, current error is: [OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
[OKAY] Trimming display Output to 138 Columns
6:03:43 PM web.1 |  Error: Could not find or load main class Main
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
6:03:43 PM web.1 Exited Abnormally

Comment: Have you run `mvn install` yet? Are you on Windows?